# Manually set canvas height in Storybook - Canvas is too low and doesn't fit component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, storybook

I have this component that I wanted to add to storybook. It worked, just the styling was off a little but I could fix that by adding the inline style position: absolute.
So now it looks like this:

```
const Template: any = (args: any): any => ({
  components: { Teaser },
  setup() {
    return { args };
  },
  template: '<teaser style="position: absolute" v-bind="args" :image="args.image"/>',
});
```

However, even though this fixes the style of the component, the canvas height in storybook where the component is displayed dropped to a minimum and most of it got cut off: [image]

I don't want to set a higher canvas globally but only for this component and **I already tried adding another style like height=400px**, which has worked for me in similar cases but not in this one.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `postition: absolute` is doing you any favor here. Since you're removing the element from the DOM flow (thus causing the canvas shrinking in height).

Have you looked at using decorators to change the story styling?
https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/decorators

Comment: I just did, it doesn't do anything and the styling of the component itself is also off again without the position: absolute :( I know using position is not a pretty workaround but as for the styling itself it seems to work, just messes with the canvas

Comment: Hmm.. good thing that styling the canvas seems to work, annoying that the component's styling seems to be off. You could try wrapping the story in an element with a `relative` positioning, also giving the wrapping element a height, and then position your component `absolute`?

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it was adding a div with class flex around the component like this:

`template: '<div class="flex"><lms-teaser v-bind="args" :image="args.image"/></div>',`

Simple but effective